# Use a Dask Cluster in a PythonScriptStep

Tags: dask, azure-machine-learning-service

Is it possible to have a multi-node Dask cluster be the compute for a `PythonScriptStep` with AML Pipelines?

We have a `PythonScriptStep` that uses `featuretools`'s, deep feature synthesis (`dfs`) ([docs](https://docs.featuretools.com/en/stable/generated/featuretools.dfs.html)). `ft.dfs()` has a param, `n_jobs` which allows for parallelization. When we run on a single machine, the job takes three hours, and runs much faster on a Dask. How can I operationalize this within an Azure ML pipeline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've been working and recently released a `dask_cloudprovider.AzureMLCluster` that might be of interest to you: [link to repo](https://github.com/dask/dask-cloudprovider). You can install it via `pip install dask-cloudprovider`.

The `AzureMLCluster` instantiates Dask cluster on AzureML service with elasticity of scaling up to 100s of nodes should you require that. The only required parameter is the `Workspace` object, but you can pass your own `ComputeTarget` should you choose to.

An example of how to use it you can [found here](https://github.com/drabastomek/GTC/blob/master/SJ_2020/workshop/1_Setup/Setup.ipynb). In this example I use my custom GPU/RAPIDS docker image but you can use any images within the `Environment` class.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to dask_cloudprovider. But, the sample code (https://github.com/drabastomek/GTC/blob/master/SJ_2020/workshop/1_Setup/Setup.ipynb) doesn't describe how to use AzureML Pipeline/PythonScriptStep on top of Dask Cluster. Any pointer would be appreciated.